# Question about simulating a robot using Stageros

Tags: navigation, stage, dwa-local-planner

I am new to ROS.
I am using Navigation Stack on Stageros to control a robot. I have a problem with the behavior of the robot when it moves to avoid obstacles in the direction of travel, and I need help to determine the cause and solve the problem.

[Here is a video of it in action.](https://youtu.be/JeUOQWd96fM)

The environment is as follows
・Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
・ROS melodic

The local planner we are using is DWAPlannerROS.
The configuration files are as follows.

dwa_local_planner_params.yaml:

```
DWAPlannerROS:
  acc_lim_theta: 3.2
  acc_lim_x: 2.5
  acc_lim_y: 2.5
  max_vel_x: 1.0
  max_vel_y: 0.15
  min_vel_x: 0.0
  min_vel_y: -0.1
  max_vel_trans: 0.65
  min_vel_trans: 0.1
  max_vel_theta: 1.0
  min_vel_theta: 0.4
  goal_distance_bias: 32.0 
  path_distance_bias: 24.0 
  occdist_scale: 1.0 
  twirling_scale: 1.2 
  stop_time_buffer: 0.2 
  forward_point_distance: 0.325 
  scaling_speed: 0.25 
  max_scaling_factor: 0.2
  publish_cost_grid_pc: false 
  publish_traj_pc: true 
  global_frame_id: "odom" 
  sim_time: 1.7  
  sim_granularity: 0.025  
  angular_sim_granularity: 0.1 
  vx_samples: 3 
  vy_samples: 10  
  vth_samples: 20 
  controller_frequency: 20.0
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.2
  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.17
  theta_stopped_vel: 0.01
  trans_stopped_vel: 0.01
  oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05
  oscillation_rest_angle: 0.2
  prune_plan: true #(bool, default: true)
```

world file:

```
show_clock 0
show_clock_interval 10000
resolution 0.02
threads 4
speedup 1


define sicklaser ranger
(
  sensor(
    pose [ 0 0 0.1 0 ]
    fov 360
    range [ 0.0 7.0 ]
    samples 512
  )
  color "random"
  block( 
    points 4
    point[0] [0 0]
    point[1] [0 1]
    point[2] [1 1]
    point[3] [1 0]
    z [0 0.21]
  )
)

define floorplan model
(
  color "gray30"
  boundary 1

  gui_nose 0
  gui_grid 0
  gui_move 0
  gui_outline 0
  gripper_return 0
  fiducial_return 0
  ranger_return 0
  obstacle_return 1
)

floorplan
(
  name "my_map"
  bitmap "../twoRooms.pgm"
  #size [60.000 60.000 0.800]
  #size [80.5 80.5 0.5]
    #size [32.2 32.2 0.5]
  #size [16.1 16.1 0.5]
  #size [8.05 8.05 0]
  size [ 148.0 141.2 4.0 ]
  #pose [0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000]
  pose [  25.2  -23.0 0.0 0.0 ]

)



window
(
  size [800 800]
  
# Camera options 
  scale 20
  center [0  0]
  rotate [ 0.000  0.000 ]


# GUI options
  show_data 1
  show_flags 1
  show_blocks 1
  show_clock 1
  show_footprints 1
  show_grid 1
  show_trailarrows 0
  show_trailrise 0
  show_trailfast 0
  show_occupancy 0

)

define agent position
(
  # actual size
  size [0.36 0.36 0.22] # sizes from MobileRobots' web site

  # the pioneer's center of rotation is offset from its center of area
  origin [0 0 0 0]

  # draw a nose on the robot so we can see which way it points
  gui_nose 1

  color "random"
  drive "diff"          # Differential steering model.
  obstacle_return 1             # Can hit things.
  ranger_return 7               # reflects sonar beams
  blob_return 1                 # Seen by blobfinders  
  fiducial_return 1             # Seen as "1" fiducial finders
  sicklaser(
    pose [ 0 0 0 0 ] 
  )
  
  # [ xmin xmax ymin ymax zmin zmax amin amax ]             
  # velocity_bounds [-5.0 5.0 -5.0 5.0 0 0 -270.0 270.0 ]                   
  # acceleration_bounds [-3 3 -3 3 0 0 -270 270.0 ]
  )

#agent( pose [ 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.0 ])
agent( pose [ -1.5 0.0 0.00 0.0 ])
agent( pose [ 1.9 0.0 0.00 0.0 ])
```